# How to start application from command line without blocking but move the focus on it?

Tags: console

I am trying to start a file compare application from the console by runnning `bcompare ... &` but this will start the application without activating it (focus).

Is there a way to start it and switch to it? I'm looking for something similar to Windows start command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with [wmctrl](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/wmctrl) [image: Install wmctrl]. Install it with `sudo apt-get install wmctrl`.

Manual: [[`wmctrl` manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/wmctrl)]

Example:

```
wmctrl -a chrome
```

Switches to the desktop containing the chrome window, raises it, and gives focus.

So after starting your program, run `wmctrl -a bcompare`.

---

As for your request, this is a *not-so-elegant-way* to check if the command is available, and if not it, try to install the package. (Consider it a bad hack, I think it should be a different question to answer this properly. For starters: it should have queried the package database.)

```
package="wmctrl"
required_command="wmctrl"
installed=`type -p $required_command`
if [ "$installed" == "" ]
then
    sudo apt-get install "$package"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks! Extra points if you update the command to try to install wmctrl if it does not exist ;)

Comment: Added a simple installation method if the command does not exist, but it is more of a joke, rather than a real solution.

Answer (score 0):

append with `&` . It denotes background application.

like

> chrome &